# How to get Start Parameters for the windows service created by using Topshelf

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, windows-services, topshelf

Hi i have created a windows service using topshelf dll. But i am unable to get start parameters.

My code :-

```
class Program
    {
        public static string filePath = "C:\\";
        public static string outputXml = "C:\\Pranay";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (args.Length != 0 && !args[0].Equals("install", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && !args[0].Equals("uninstall", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //filePath = args[2];
                    //outputXml = args[3];
                }

                XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(
                    new FileInfo(".\\log4net.config"));

                var host = HostFactory.New(x =>
                {
                    x.EnableDashboard();
                    x.Service<XmlConverterService>(s =>
                    {
                        s.SetServiceName("XmlConverterService");
                        s.ConstructUsing(name => new XmlConverterService());
                        s.WhenStarted(tc =>
                        {
                            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(
                                new FileInfo(".\\log4net.config"));
                            tc.Start(args);
                        });
                        s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
                    });

                    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                    x.SetDescription("I have created this to service");
                    x.SetDisplayName("PranayXMLService");
                    x.SetServiceName("PranayXMLService");
                });

                host.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

I have installed it and when i am trying to pass start argument as:-

```
sc start PranayXmlConverter C:\\ C:\\Pranay
```

nothing is being passed. To check what i am getting in `args` i have passed it in `start(args)` method and when i printed what is in `args` i got to know the output was as follows:

**-displayname

PranayXMLService

-servicename:PranayXMLService**

My question is how can i get start parameter and where?